# Replicate element in a list of vector if length(vector)==1 in R

Tags: r

I have a simple list of vectors and I would like to replicate the element of every vectors that have a length of 1.

```
mylist <- list(c(98, 102), c(175, 177), c(239, 240), c(146, 147, 168, 169
), c(240, 242), c(363, 391), c(144, 146, 146), 197, 126, c(181, 
192))

results  <- lapply(mylist,function(x) if(length(x)==1) rep(x[1],each=2))
```

I get in results the expected replicates, but how to also keep in results all the vectors of length >1 ? I can't find a correct way to do this. I'm pretty sure this is quite simple...

Thanx for helping

Comment: use the other half of `if`... `else`:  `lapply(mylist,function(x) if(length(x)==1) rep(x[1],each=2) else x)`

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I tried that but with ifelse without success... This works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the `else` statement to leave the elements with more values

```
mylist <- list(c(98, 102), c(175, 177), c(239, 240), c(146, 147, 168, 169
), c(240, 242), c(363, 391), c(144, 146, 146), 197, 126, c(181, 
192))

results  <- lapply(mylist,function(x) if(length(x)==1) rep(x[1],each=2) else x)
```

Which results in

```
[[1]]
[1]  98 102

[[2]]
[1] 175 177

[[3]]
[1] 239 240

[[4]]
[1] 146 147 168 169

[[5]]
[1] 240 242

[[6]]
[1] 363 391

[[7]]
[1] 144 146 146

[[8]]
[1] 197 197

[[9]]
[1] 126 126

[[10]]
[1] 181 192
```